# Sort Integer Array from Text file in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi I have a file named asc.txt and this file has integers in each line like 9 8 100 and in other line suppose 2 1 100. Goal is to sort each line in ascending. The code below is only sorting one line. When I add other line, it doe not sort. Thanks

```
<?php
```

//Split file by newlines "\n" into an array using explode()

```
$variable=file_get_contents('asc.txt');
$file = explode(" ",$variable);
```

//sort array with sort()

```
sort($file);
echo implode(",\n", $file);

?>
```

Input in file is

```
1 9 8 100
2 1 5 1000
```

Output should be

```
1 8 9 100
1 2 5 1000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do with:

```
foreach (new SplFileObject('asc.txt') as $lineInFile) {
    preg_match_all('/\d+/', $lineInFile, $numbersInFile);
    sort($numbersInFile[0], SORT_NUMERIC);
    echo implode(' ', $numbersInFile[0]), PHP_EOL;
};
```

This will stream read your input file, match all the numbers in a line into an array, sort that array and output it. Depending on your sorting needs, you can also use [`natsort()`](http://php.net/natsort)

As for outputting this:

I am assuming you are using this script on the command line. If you want to display this with line breaks in your browser, add `<br>` elements or use `nl2br` or wrap the output into a `<pre>` element or format it with CSS's `white-space: pre`.

Answer (score 0):

When you explode your string, set your needle to "\n"

```
<?php
//Split file by newlines "\n" into an array using explode()

$variable=file_get_contents('asc.txt');
$file = explode("\n",$variable); // NOTICE "\n" AS NEEDLE

//sort array with sort()
sort($file);
echo implode(",\n", $file);

?>
```

Comment: This would only work if each integer was on its own line.

Comment: @Edward OP said: __"The code below is only sorting one line. When I add other line, it doe not sort. Thanks"__ hence the answer.

Comment: this works, however the comma should probably be removed because the leading character will be a comma on output.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes I guess, that part belongs to OP

Comment: ...which is why I posted a comment to that effect under his question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if your file uses \n style new lines, else try replacing \n for \r.

```
$variable=file_get_contents('asc.txt');
$file = explode(" ", str_replace("\n", " ", $variable) );


sort($file);
echo implode(",\n", $file);
?>
```

Comment: Above code will place all lines on one before exploding into the array of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

```
$lines_array = file("asc.txt");
natsort($lines_array);
print_r($lines_array);

//if you need to echo the lines you can use:

foreach($lines_array as $line){
   echo $line."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2 1 100

    [2] => 5 1 100

    [0] => 9 8 100

    [3] => 16 1 100
)
```

---

`natsort()` will sort the numerics correctly (as opposed to `asort()`)

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question (which I apparently didnt because my answer was accepted), this is not output the OP wants. 2 1 100 should be 1 2 100, 5 1 100 should be 1 5 100 and so on.

Comment: I guess I was the one that misunderstood the question, my apologies.

Comment: @Gordon [OP wrote this to Pedro....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064834/sort-integer-array-from-text-file-in-php#comment53948731_33064834) which does output `1 9 8 100 2 1 5 1000` - IMO, OP is throwing everyone into a tailspin. Edit: darn it... one character off, my bad. Nonetheless, still a tailspin.

Comment: The OP question wasn't clear enough and mislead us...

Comment: @PedroLobito agreed. OP needs to grasp basic HTML. ;-)